# Zend naming of views

Tags: zend-framework, view, naming-conventions

I am using Zend Framework 1.12.0

This is a beginner's question, but I have not found the answer anywhere in the Zend docs or elsewhere.

If I have a controller called "ControlThis" and an action called "doThat", how should the corresponding view template be named?

/views/scripts/controlThis/doThat.phtml ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Controller: IndexController.php

For the controller, name it with a capital letter for the first word followed by Controller with a capital letter.

Action: public function someactionAction() {}

For the action name, it should be all lower caps followed by Action with a capital letter.  Be sure not to use camel casing for your action names.

View: /views/scripts/index/someaction.phtml

For the view, all in lower caps

Comment: There's no issue with camel-cased action names - `blogPostAction()` -> `blog-post.phtml`

Answer (score 0):

Both view folders and view scripts are always lower case and words are separated with dashes "-" instead of using upper case letter

Example:

```
TestController::listOfUsersAction => views/scripts/test/list-of-users.phtml
EmailSettingsController::primarySettingsAction => views/scripts/email-settings/primary-settings.phtml
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set this name to the view :

> do-that.phtml

In the url, you have to put :

> /control-this/do-that/